# EntityManager causes Resource Leak when created using SharedEntityManagerCreator

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I am creating EntityManager instance sort-of manually like this (without using `@PersistenceContext` annotation)

```
private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = (EntityManagerFactory) ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean("projEntityManagerFactory");
    
private Boolean update(String par) {
    EntityManager entityManager = SharedEntityManagerCreator.createSharedEntityManager(entityManagerFactory);
    
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(Constants.UPDATE_PROCEDURE);
    
    //other update query builder code
    
    return (Boolean) query.getOutputParameterValue(4);
}
```

I am getting warnings related to resource leakage. I assumed it may be because the `entityManager` is used but never closed.

What I tried:

1. I added `@Transactional` annotation on top of my method so that the query is bound in a transaction and the resources are closed when the transaction ends.
2. I read this [document](https://javanotepad.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-close-jpa-entitymanger-in-web.html) , and it states that I should use `EntityTransaction` and close the connection with `entityManager.close()`

Which one is right? How can I resolve the resource leak warning?

Comment: 1. Doesn't work because you are creating an `EntityManager` yourself which is not under control of the Spring transaction management. So you need to close it yourself afterwards (so option 2). But why areyou creating ityourself in the first place?

Comment: @M.Deinum The reason for creating it myself is unclear, but will it better to create the entityManagerFactory like this? @Autowired @Qualifier("projEntityManagerFactory") private EntityManager entityManager;` and then use @Transactional on top of the update method to prevent resource leak? –

Comment: Why not just using `@PersistenceContext`? You could use autowired, but some might frown upon that. Using `@PersistenceContext("projEntityManagerFactory")` (or whatever the actual name is you gave it in the `persistencecontext.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to predict just by looking at the code, but in order to return the DB connection after the transaction is completed, JPA open-in-view (OSIV) must be changed to false. And I think the second method, closing the entity manager directly, is suitable for your situation. However, in general, registering the entity manager as a Spring bean and using it through DI will be more efficient in managing resources. If you create and use it yourself, please be sure to return the resources.